# Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in

Tags: php

Hi I already checked all the posts with the same title but none helps me. First of all I'm a complete newbie and trying to make sendmail.php to get the information from short contact form  I got a premade script and try to add a checkbox but not sure how to grep and send is the box checked or not and send to email.

This is the script:

```
$to="admin@email.com";/*Your Email*/
$subject=$_REQUEST['subject'];

$date=date("l, F jS, Y");
$time=date("h:i A");

$firstName=$_REQUEST['name'];
$email=$_REQUEST['email'];
$phone=$_REQUEST['phone'];  
$hosting = (implode(',', $_POST['hosting']));


$msg="  Message from contact form sent:  $date, hour: $time.\n  
    Име: $firstName\n
    Email: $email\n 
    Телефон: $phone 
    Хостинг:  ".$hosting."\r\n
    ";



if($email=="") {
echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
          <a class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>×</a>
          <strong>Warning!</strong> Fill all boxes.
      </div>";
} else {
mail($to,$subject,$msg,"From:".$email);
echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>
          <a class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>×</a>
          <strong>Will contact with you.</strong>
      </div>";
}
```

And this is the part of the contact form code :

```
input type="checkbox" name="hosting[]" value="Get Hosting"
```

See:

[image]

Comment: `var_dump($_POST['hosting'])` ??

Comment: You don't check if the `$_POST['hosting']` has been set, or if it's an array.

Comment: You can also drop redundant parentheses around `implode`

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I will try to see whats happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you need in the variable hosting or why you define the input tag as an array when there is only one value available. You should use

```
<input type="checkbox" name="hosting" value="Get Hosting">
```

in your form and can use this instead of implode

```
$hosting = isset($_POST['hosting']) ? $_POST['hosting'] : 'No Hosting';
```

It will write "Get Hosting" if the checkbox is set and "No Hosting" if not.

Sincerly

Comment: Thank you Philipp, that work for me i wanted to get information in the email wherever the person want this service so is it checked the box or not.  Now i understand what i sould do.